# Flutter: ChangeNotifierProvider with an initial network request

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a Widget which represents a list of movies, in my model I have the getMovies() function which retrieves the list of movies from a network request:

```
enum MovieListState { IDLE, LOADING, ERROR }

class MovieListModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  MovieListModel(this._client);

  GatewayClient _client;

  MovieListState _viewState = MovieListState.LOADING;

  MovieListState get viewState => _viewState;

  set viewState(MovieListState value) {
    _viewState = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<List<Movie>> getMovies() async {
    try {
      viewState = MovieListState.LOADING;
      var movies = await _client.getMovies();
      viewState = MovieListState.IDLE;
      return movies;
    } on KoException catch (e) {
      viewState = MovieListState.ERROR;
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Then from the widget I want to build the layout based on the state of the request:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    state = Provider.of<AppState>(context);
    var model = MovieListModel(Provider.of<GatewayClient>(context));

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MovieListModel>.value(
        value: model,
        child: Consumer<MovieListModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {
          if (model.viewState == MovieListState.IDLE) {
            return _getList(); // Method which generates the content with the retrieved values
          } else if (model.viewState == MovieListState.LOADING) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text(_static.translate(context).movieListError),
            );
          }
        }));
  }
```

The problem is, how can I trigger the network call getMovies() at the very beggining of the widget initialization? I tried to manually call the getMovies() method in different points but I have either an error, or the call is repeating each time the widget is calling its build() method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using FutureProvider:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureProvider<List<Movie>>.value(
      value: _model.getMovies(),
      initialData: List<Movie>(),
      catchError: (context, error) {
        return null;
      },
      child: Consumer<List<Movie>>(
        builder: (context, data, widget) {
          // ...
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the call to getMovies() be in the initState()? Because if you make the call within the build() method then any changes to your UI which would trigger the build method resulting in unnecessary API call.

Comment: initState(), as the name implies, is called just one time. Probably not the behaviour wanted in this scenario.